# How to show $ \text{Re}f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{Im}f(x')}{x'-x}dx' $

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show

$$ \text{Re}f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}  \mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{Im}f(x')}{x'-x}dx' $$

$$ \text{Im}f(x) = -\frac{1}{\pi}  \mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{Re}f(x')}{x'-x}dx' $$

where $ \mathcal{P}$ is the Cauchy principal value.

Comment: Those are [Kramers–Kronig Relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers–Kronig_relations).